# How can I appear as an "anonymous animal" on Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive, google-docs, google-drive-sharing

How do you change your title to an anonymous animal on shared Google Drive documents?

I'm currently in a college class of about 150 and I'm the only person doesn't seem to know how to make themselves anonymous on our study guides. It's been a bit awkward studying for our midterm.

Answer (score 7):

By logging out of your Google account before visiting these shared Google Docs.

I'm not aware of any setting inside the Google account to appear anonymous.

Comment: [Here's the relevant Google help page](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2494888?hl=en) that explains how this feature works: "If you share or open a file with a link, you may not see the names of people who view it.
 - People you didn’t invite individually will show as anonymous animals when they’re in the file.
- People you invite individually will show by name when they’re in the file. 
You can only see other people’s names when you give them individual permission to view a file or if they are part of a mailing list."

Comment: So this answer is one solution to appear as an "anonymous animal" on a file that is visible to anyone with the link, but you should edit the answer to explain *why* this works.

Answer (score 2):

Open the document in a private/incognito browser session:

Mozilla Firefox: Right click document link -> Open Link in New Private Window.

Google Chrome: Right click document link -> Open Link in New Incognito Window.

Comment: [Here's the relevant Google help page](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2494888?hl=en) that explains how this feature works: "If you share or open a file with a link, you may not see the names of people who view it.
 - People you didn’t invite individually will show as anonymous animals when they’re in the file.
- People you invite individually will show by name when they’re in the file. 
You can only see other people’s names when you give them individual permission to view a file or if they are part of a mailing list."

Comment: So this answer is one solution to appear as an "anonymous animal" on a file that is visible to anyone with the link, but you should edit the answer to explain *why* this works.